# Why confounding factor has to correlated with independent variable?

Tags: experiment-design, confounding

One assumption of linear regression is the independent variables should be independent of each other. But in experimental design, when we build a linear regression to measure the causal impact of the interested variable, we control for confounding factors. The confounding factors are factors both related to the interesting variable(independent variable) and dependent variable. It sounds contrast with the assumption of linear regression.  Can anybody explain to me why this happens?

Comment: It sounds like you're assuming that the confounding variables are some of the independent variables. Should that necessarily be the case? Incidentally, the new causal revolution defines confounders much more precisely than you have laid out: A confounding variable is one that sets up a backdoor path from $X$ to $Y,$ where we think of $X$ as the explanatory variable, and $Y$ as the effect variable.

Comment: Based on my understanding, some of the confounding variables are observable and others cannot. If they can observable, we should control them in regression, which means they are some of the independent variables.

Comment: I prefer a different terminology, from the new causal revolution. You have causal variables, or explanatory variables, call them $X.$ You have the effect variable, call it $Y.$ Then you have possible confounders, call them $Z.$ You might well end up with some $Z$ variables on the RHS of your linear regressions, but that doesn't make them explanatory variables. Very important: just because a variable is correlated with an explanatory variable doesn't mean it's a confounder, and you might need to NOT control for it. A causal diagram is the best way to figure out these things.

Comment: "One assumption of linear regression is the independent variables should be independent of each other." That is not an assumption in regression. The independent variables must be uncorrelated with the disturbance. Do you have a citation for this statement?

Comment: In statistics and econometrics, a confounding factor is a variable that influences both the dependent variable and the independent variable.For example, if you are researching whether a lack of exercise leads to weight gain, lack of exercise is the independent variable. weight gain is the dependent variable.

A confounding variable here would be any other variable that affects both of these variables, such as the age.

Comment: One assumption of multiple linear regression is no multicollinearity. I just checked again it means independent variables should not be highly correlated with each other.

Comment: I'm getting the impression that there's a lot less to any disagreement here than meets the eye. Here's what I would recommend: type up a particular linear regression question that you have, and I would strongly recommend that you include as complete a causal diagram as you can. From the diagram, you can do an awful lot, such as figure out what should be in the regression, what should not be in the regression, adjustments you might have to make, where you might consider adding an instrumental variable, or how you could set up a frontdoor adjustment.